# Device Anywhere - App may not be signed

Tags: ios, testing, device

I am building my application using XCode 6 and App Store provisioning profile. After creating the application, I tried to upload it in Device Anywhere (Keynote), but it is giving me an error saying the app might be unsigned and that I need to sign it. I also tried it with AdHoc profile, but it is the same.

To verify, I installed the application on my test device, the one signed with AdHoc and it is working properly. I also verified the IPAs with security cms command and the IPA are getting generated properly.

Any help regarding this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Build the application using AdHoc profile and during upload selection the option to re-sign it. Also using Device Anywhere version 7.0 or the latest one. That will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the device in which you are trying to deploy the code, registered under the same provisioning profile you are trying ? Please check on this.

A provisioning profile binds

- Certificate
- App ID
- Device UDID.

So basically only if your device is under this particular provisioning profile, you will be able to deploy.

Comment: In DeviceAnywhere I am not able to get the UDID of the device. I am trying to deploy the IPA in iOS 7 and iOS 8. Even if I select the option to sign using Keynote Profile, it does not get installed. So do we need to deploy AdHoc profile signed IPA or AppStore signed IPA.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Build the application using AdHoc profile and during upload selection the option to re-sign it. Also using Device Anywhere version 7.0 or the latest one. That will resolve the issue.